# Pandas: Fill empty values with the first value of same duplicated names/keys group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 2 columns: `name` and `id`

In the `name` column I have a couple of duplicates and in the `id` column I have an empty value for the duplicates of same `name`.

What I want is to fill that empty value with the value of the first iteration

For example:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=["name","id"])
df1["name"]=["a","b","c","a","d","e","b"]
df1["id"]=[1,2,3,"",4,5,""]


  name  id
0    a   1
1    b   2
2    c   3
3    a   
4    d   4
5    e   5
6    b
```

For the second iteration of `"a"` and `"b"` I have an empty value

What I want:

```
df1["id"]=[1,2,3,1,4,5,2]
```

How can I fill that empty value with the value of the first iteration ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can group the name by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get the first entry of each group by [`.transform('first')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html).  Then replace the empty string with these first entries in same name group by [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), as follows:

```
df1['id'] = df1['id'].replace('', np.nan).fillna(df1.groupby('name')['id'].transform('first')).astype(int)
```

If your `id` column already contains some `NaN` values and you don't want to touch on these values, you can also use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to conditionally replace the empty string values by `groupby` [`.transform('first')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) values, as follows:

```
df1['id'] = df1['id'].mask(df1['id'] == '', df1.groupby('name')['id'].transform('first'))
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  name  id
0    a   1
1    b   2
2    c   3
3    a   1
4    d   4
5    e   5
6    b   2
```

Answer (score 0):

A few more [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) options via

[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
df1['id'] = np.where(
    df1['id'].eq(''),
    df1.groupby('name')['id'].transform('first'),
    df1['id']
)
```

and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc):

```
df1.loc[df1['id'].eq(''), 'id'] = df1.groupby('name')['id'].transform('first')
```

`df1`:

```
  name id
0    a  1
1    b  2
2    c  3
3    a  1
4    d  4
5    e  5
6    b  2
```